# Draw a bended arrow between two points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am producing the figure below using the following gnuplot code. I want to draw a bended arrow from the point labeled *l=0* to *l=1* with head.

**Code**

```
reset session
# Ranges
set xrange [-1:6]
set yrange [-2:1]
# Term options
set terminal postscript eps 
set termoption font "Times, 30"
# set termoption
set style line 1 lc rgb 'black' lw 3 lt 1 pt 7 ps 2
# Data points
$DATA<<EOD
0   0 
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
EOD 
set output "Anderson_lattice.eps"
# set arrow
set arrow 1 from -0.5, -1.5 to 5.5, -1.5 lc rgb 'black' lw 5 
set arrow 2 from -0.5, -1.5 to -0.5, -0.5 lc rgb 'black' lw 5
set label 1 "{/Times-Italic=30 {/Symbol e}_{l}}" at -0.75, -0.3 tc rgb "black"
set arrow 3 from -0.25, -1.0 to 0.25, -1.0 ls 1 nohead
set arrow 5 from 1 - 0.25, -0.75 to 1 + 0.25, -0.75 ls 1 nohead
set arrow 6 from 2 - 0.25, -0.5 to 2 + 0.25, -0.5 ls 1 nohead
set arrow 7 from 3 - 0.25, -1.35 to 3 + 0.25, -1.35 ls 1 nohead
set arrow 8 from 4 - 0.25, -1.0 to 4 + 0.25, -1 ls 1 nohead
set arrow 9 from 5 - 0.25, -0.85 to 4 + 0.25, -0.85 ls 1 nohead
set arrow 10 from 6 - 0.25, -1.25 to 6 + 0.25, -1.25 ls 1 nohead
set label 2 "{/Times-Italic=30 sites}" at 5.5, -1.65 tc 'black'
set label 3 "{/Times-Italic=30 l=0}" at 2.7, -0.25 tc 'black'
set label 4 "{/Times-Italic=30 l=1}" at 1 + 2.7, -0.25 tc 'black'
unset xtics; unset ytics; unset border
plot $DATA using 1:2 with p ls 1 notitle
unset output
```

**Result**
[image: Result of the code above]

How do I do that?

Comment: Check out [this link](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/04/bending-arrows-delaying-plot.html).

Comment: Very helpful to start and necessary to understand the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware that gnuplot offers a feature for directly drawing a bent arrow.

**Edit:**
*(I removed my initial approach since it has no advantage over using Cubic Bézier. And added some more flexibility to the second approach.)*

I completely agree with @GRSousaJr that Cubic Bézier curves give much more flexibility in drawing bent arrows. At the same time you can also draw straight arrows.

Based on @GRSousaJr's approach, my suggestions would be the following:
instead of entering absolute values for the control points, I would prefer relative or absolute angles and relative distances. This has the advantage that you don't have to care about absolute numbers, especially when two arrows should have the same proportions but have different absolute start/endpoints.
All parameters for the arrows are in the datablock `$myArrows`.

**Some explanations:**

1. for the Cubic Bézier curves 4 points are used: `p0,p1,p2,p3`, where `p0` and `p3` are the start and end points, respectively. `p1` and `p2` are points which control the curvature. `p0x, p0y, ... p3x, p3y` are the `x` and `y` components, respectively.
2. in contrast to @GRSousaJr's solution the control points `p1` and `p2` are not given in absolute values but calculated from `p0` and `p3` and the angles `a0` and `a3` and the radii `r0` and `r3`.
3. the angles of the arrow at the points `p0` and `p3` can be given absolute or relative to the direction of `p0` to `p3`. The parameter `e` tells which end has relative angle and which end absolute angle. 0=angles at both ends relative, 1=start angle relative, end angle absolute, 2=start angle absolute, end angle relative, 3=angles at both ends absolute. For the relative angle you first need to calculate the angle between `p0` and `p3` (function `AngleP0P3()`)
4. the distance of the control points `p1` and `p2` from the points `p0` and `p3` are given in relative values `r0` and `r3` with respect to the distance between `p0` and `p3`. That's why there is the function `Length()`. `0.5` is a good value to start with.
5. note that the functions `AngleP0P3(n)` and `Length(n)` actually do not depend on `n`. That is just to shorten the code. These functions use the parameters `p1x, ..., p3y`, and when calling `AngleP0P3(0)` the function will take the current values of `p1x, ..., p3y`. This is shorter than e.g. `Angle(p0x,p0y,p3x,p3y)`.
6. the function `ArrowInit(i)` is to collect or initialize the values for `p1x, ..., p3y` from the `i`th row of datablock `$myArrows`.
7. the line of the arrows are simply plotted in a for loop as parametric function in `t` with the range `t[0:1]`. For every `i` in the plot command `ArrowInit(i)` is called to get the corresponding parameters from the datablock `$myArrows`.
8. The angle of the arrow in point `p3` is in the direction from `p2` to `p3`, i.e. the tangent of the Bézier curve in point `p3`. However you don't want the line, but just the arrow. So far, I don't have a better approach than plotting a short vector from 99% of the arrow path to 100% of the arrow path.

**Some comments on usage:**

1. in order to "see" the correct angles you specify in `$myArrows`, your plot has to have the same aspect ratio as your x and y ranges. In the below examples it is `x[0:20]` and `y[0:10]`, hence, set the aspect ratio of the graph to `0.5`, i.e. at the beginning `set size 0.5`.
2. the direction of the arrow head is the tangent in point `p3`. If you have a strong curvature at `p3`, the arrow head might look "bad", although the arrow head is in the correct angle. In such cases, increase the length `r3` a little.
3. You can also draw straight arrows, see Arrow1. Just set `a0=0,a3=0` and `e=0`.

Tested with gnuplot 5.2.8

**Code:**

```
### workaround for bent arrows
reset session
set size ratio 0.5

#    p0x   p0y    a0   r0   p3x   p3y   a3   r3  e     color
$myArrows <<EOD                    
 1  1.00  1.00     0  0.5  3.00  3.00    0  0.5  0  0xff0000
 2  3.00  1.00     0  0.5  5.00  3.00    0  0.5  1  0x00c000
 3  5.00  1.00     0  0.5  7.00  3.00    0  0.5  2  0x0000ff
 4  7.00  1.00     0  0.5  9.00  3.00    0  0.5  3  0xff00ff
 5  1.00  4.00     0  0.5  3.00  6.00   90  0.5  0  0xff0000
 6  3.00  4.00     0  0.5  5.00  6.00   90  0.5  1  0x00c000
 7  5.00  4.00     0  0.5  7.00  6.00   90  0.5  2  0x0000ff
 8  7.00  4.00     0  0.5  9.00  6.00   90  0.5  3  0xff00ff
 9  1.00  7.00    90  0.5  3.00  9.00    0  0.5  0  0xff0000
10  3.00  7.00    90  0.5  5.00  9.00    0  0.5  1  0x00c000
11  5.00  7.00    90  0.5  7.00  9.00    0  0.5  2  0x0000ff
12  7.00  7.00    90  0.5  9.00  9.00    0  0.5  3  0xff00ff
13 11.00  1.00    45  0.5 13.00  3.00  -45  0.5  0  0xff0000
14 13.00  1.00    45  0.5 15.00  3.00  -45  0.5  1  0x00c000
15 15.00  1.00    45  0.5 17.00  3.00  -45  0.5  2  0x0000ff
16 17.00  1.00    45  0.5 19.00  3.00  -45  0.5  3  0xff00ff
17 11.00  4.00   -45  0.5 13.00  6.00  -45  0.5  0  0xff0000
18 13.00  4.00   -45  0.5 15.00  6.00  -45  0.5  1  0x00c000
19 15.00  4.00   -45  0.5 17.00  6.00  -45  0.5  2  0x0000ff
20 17.00  4.00   -45  0.5 19.00  6.00  -45  0.5  3  0xff00ff
21 11.00  7.00     0  0.5 15.00  9.00   90  0.5  1  0x00c000
22 15.00  7.00     0  0.5 19.00  9.00    0  0.5  1  0x00c000
EOD

set angle degrees
# Angle between p0 and p3 (range: -90° <= angle < 270°), NaN if dx=dy=0
AngleP0P3(n)  = (dy=p3y-p0y,dx=p3x-p0x)==0 ? (dy==0 ? NaN : sgn(dy)*90) : \
                (dx<0 ? 180 : 0) + atan(dy/dx)

# Parameter e: determines which ends have relative or absolute angles
# 0: both ends relative
# 1: start relative, end absolute,
# 2: start absolute, end relative
# 3: both ends absolute
AngleAbs(i) = int(word($myArrows[i],10))   # to set all arrows equal, use: AngleAbs(i) = 0,1,2, or 3
Angle(i,p) = word($myArrows[i],p) + \
             ((p==4 && AngleAbs(i)&2) || (p==8 && AngleAbs(i)&1) ? 0 : AngleP0P3(0))
Length(n) = sqrt((p3x-p0x)**2 + (p3y-p0y)**2)
Color(i)  = word($myArrows[i],11)

ArrowInit(i) = (p0x=word($myArrows[i],2),p0y=word($myArrows[i],3), \
           p3x=word($myArrows[i],6),p3y=word($myArrows[i],7), \
           p1x=p0x+Length(0)*word($myArrows[i],5)*cos(Angle(i,4)), \
           p1y=p0y+Length(0)*word($myArrows[i],5)*sin(Angle(i,4)), \
           p2x=p3x-Length(0)*word($myArrows[i],9)*cos(Angle(i,8)), \
           p2y=p3y-Length(0)*word($myArrows[i],9)*sin(Angle(i,8)))

# Cubic Bézier curves function with t[0:1] as parameter
# p0: start point, p1: 1st control point, p2: 2nd control point, p3: endpoint
px(t) = (-p0x + 3*p1x - 3*p2x + p3x)*t**3 + (3*p0x - 6*p1x + 3*p2x)*t**2 + (-3*p0x + 3*p1x)*t + p0x
py(t) = (-p0y + 3*p1y - 3*p2y + p3y)*t**3 + (3*p0y - 6*p1y + 3*p2y)*t**2 + (-3*p0y + 3*p1y)*t + p0y

# set linestyles and arrowstyles
do for [i=1:|$myArrows|] {
    set style line i lw 2 lc rgb Color(i)
    set style arrow i head size 0.20,15,45 fixed filled ls i
}

set key out noautotitle below
set xrange [0:20]
set xtics 1
set format x ""
set grid xtics ls -1 lc rgb "gray"
set yrange [0:10]
set ytics 1
set format y ""
set grid ytics ls -1 lc rgb "gray"

plot for [i=1:|$myArrows|] [0:1] '+' u (ArrowInit(i),px($1)):(py($1)) w l ls i, \
     for [i=1:|$myArrows|] [0:1] '+' u (ArrowInit(i),px(0.99)):(py(0.99)): \
     (px(1)-px(0.99)):(py(1)-py(0.99)) every ::0::0 w vec as i, \
     $myArrows u 2:3:1 w labels offset 0,-0.7, \
     keyentry w l ls 1 ti "both ends relative angles", \
     keyentry w l ls 2 ti "start relative, end absolute angle", \
     keyentry w l ls 3 ti "start absolute, end relative angle", \
     keyentry w l ls 4 ti "both ends absolute angles"
### end of code

exit
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The last version of your approach looks like great. So much more robust flexible and demand no concern about the control points. I'm still working on a version where is possible define the control points using the interactive `wxt` terminal! But, just a sketch yet. Great job!

Answer (score 3):

I created (at least in my mind) an "enhanced" version of [@theozh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389081/11369382), which allows somewhat control over arrow form.

The idea is to use a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to draw the bent arrow. The `head` is drawn as on @theozh's answer, i.e., using `vectors`. The initial (`xi,yi`) and final points (`xy,yf`), as well the control points (`xc1,yc1` and `xc2,yc2`), are passed to a function using `call` command. The function creates a datafile using the`id`, like a `tag` on standard `arrow`, defined by user, and associates a variavel (e.g. `BentArrow_id`) name to such datafile. Each created datafile contain:

1. the control points
2. the datapoints to create the `arrow`, and
3. the datapoints do create `head`

as three indexable datablocks (`0`, `1` and `2`, respectively), like this:

```
# Block index 0 (control points)
 1.000000e+00   -1.250000e+00
 1.250000e+00    0.000000e+00

 2.800000e+00   -5.000000e-01
 3.000000e+00   -7.500000e-01


# Block index 1 (arrow)
 1.000000e+00   -1.250000e+00
 1.016539e+00   -1.177084e+00
 1.036070e+00   -1.108272e+00
 1.058468e+00   -1.043468e+00
 ...             ...
 2.927437e+00   -6.862240e-01
 2.949992e+00   -7.027320e-01
 2.969690e+00   -7.189280e-01
 2.986401e+00   -7.347160e-01
 3.000000e+00   -7.500000e-01


# Block index 2 (head)
 2.986401e+00   -7.347160e-01    1.359880e-02   -1.528400e-02
 3.000000e+00   -7.500000e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
```

To draw the bent arrow, the `plot` command must be composed by three parts:

```
plot \
    ...
    BentArrow_id i 0 u 1:2 w lp ...,\
    BentArrow_id i 1 u 1:2 w lines ...,\
    BentArrow_id i 2 u 1:2:3:4 w vectors ...,\
   ...
```

Each part corresponds to a piece of arrow (the control points, the arrow itself, and the head, respectively).

To better show the script (called `BentArrow.fct`) working, consider the example.

```
reset
set terminal wxt size 500,500
set size ratio -1
set grid ls -1 lc "gray"
unset key
set tics out nomirror
set xrange [-0.25:9.25]
set yrange [-0.25:9.25]

set style arrow 1 head size 0.25,15,45 fixed filled lc "red"

BentArrow(id,xi,yi,x1,y1,x2,y2,xf,yf) = \
    sprintf("call 'BentArrow.fct' '%g' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f'", \
        id, xi,yi, x1,y1, x2,y2, xf,yf )

#             id,  xi,yi , xc1,yc1, xc2,yc2,  xf,yf
eval BentArrow(1, 1.0,1.0, 2.0,2.0, 3.0,0.0, 4.0,1.0)
eval BentArrow(2, 5.0,1.0, 6.0,0.0, 7.0,2.0, 8.0,1.0)
eval BentArrow(3, 1.0,4.0, 2.0,3.0, 3.0,3.0, 4.0,4.0)
eval BentArrow(4, 5.0,4.0, 6.0,5.0, 7.0,5.0, 8.0,4.0)
eval BentArrow(5, 1.0,7.0, 5.0,5.0, 0.0,5.0, 4.0,7.0)
eval BentArrow(6, 5.0,7.0, 5.0,9.0, 6.0,7.0, 8.0,7.0)

CtrlPoints = "w lp ls -1 pt 6 ps 1 pi -1"
StyleArrow = "w lines lc 'red' lw 2"
StyleHead  = "w vec as 1"

plot \
    BentArrow_1 i 0 u 1:2     @CtrlPoints ,\
    BentArrow_1 i 1 u 1:2     @StyleArrow ,\
    BentArrow_1 i 2 u 1:2:3:4 @StyleHead  ,\
    BentArrow_2 i 0 u 1:2     @CtrlPoints ,\
    BentArrow_2 i 1 u 1:2     @StyleArrow ,\
    BentArrow_2 i 2 u 1:2:3:4 @StyleHead  ,\
    BentArrow_3 i 0 u 1:2     @CtrlPoints ,\
    BentArrow_3 i 1 u 1:2     @StyleArrow ,\
    BentArrow_3 i 2 u 1:2:3:4 @StyleHead  ,\
    BentArrow_4 i 0 u 1:2     @CtrlPoints ,\
    BentArrow_4 i 1 u 1:2     @StyleArrow ,\
    BentArrow_4 i 2 u 1:2:3:4 @StyleHead  ,\
    BentArrow_5 i 0 u 1:2     @CtrlPoints ,\
    BentArrow_5 i 1 u 1:2     @StyleArrow ,\
    BentArrow_5 i 2 u 1:2:3:4 @StyleHead  ,\
    BentArrow_6 i 0 u 1:2     @CtrlPoints ,\
    BentArrow_6 i 1 u 1:2     @StyleArrow ,\
    BentArrow_6 i 2 u 1:2:3:4 @StyleHead
```

The results

[image: bent arrow example]

Applying the script to your example, the result look like this

[image: result with control points]

Of course the control points are useful just to defining each arrow.
The variable `showCtrlPoints = "False" (default "True")` is defined to allows hide the control points on final plot.

[image: result without control points]

The script to last example is:

```
reset

# The data
$levels<<EOD
 1   0.5   -1.25            
 2   0.5   -1.00
 3   0.5   -0.75
 4   0.5   -0.50
 5   0.5   -0.25
 6   0.5   -1.25
 7   0.5   -1.00
 8   0.5   -0.75
 9   0.5   -0.50
10   0.5   -0.25
EOD

# Cubic Bézier function
BentArrow(id,xi,yi,x1,y1,x2,y2,xf,yf) = \
    sprintf("call 'BentArrow.fct' '%g' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f' '%f'", \
        id, xi,yi, x1,y1, x2,y2, xf,yf )

# Arrow styles
set style arrow 1 head size 0.2,15,45 fixed filled lc "red"
set style arrow 2 head size 0.2,15,45 fixed filled lc "web-green"
set style arrow 3 head size 0.2,15,45 fixed filled lc "blue"

# To levels
set errorbars small
unset key

# Options to drawing the bent arrows
showCtrlPoints = "False"
ArrowPoints = 50

# Calling the function
eval BentArrow(1,  1.00,-1.25,  1.25, 0.00,  2.80,-0.50,  3.00,-0.75)
eval BentArrow(2,  8.00, 0.50,  8.00, 0.00,  5.00, 0.25,  5.00,-0.25)
eval BentArrow(3,  1.00, 0.50,  2.00,-0.25,  9.00, 0.50,  10.0,-0.25)

# Macros
Points = "w p ls -1 pt 7 ps 2"
Levels = "w xerrorbars ls -1 lw 2"
CtrlPoints = "w lp ls -1 pt 6 ps 1 pi -1"
StyleArrow = "w lines lw 2"
StyleHead  = "w vectors"

# Allow to toggle between show/hide the control points
CP(n) = showCtrlPoints eq "True" ? n : NaN

plot \
    $levels u 1:2                @Points                    ,\
    "" u 1:3:(0.35)              @Levels                    ,\
    BentArrow_1 i 0 u 1:(CP($2)) @CtrlPoints                ,\
    BentArrow_1 i 1 u 1:2        @StyleArrow lc "red"       ,\
    BentArrow_1 i 2 u 1:2:3:4    @StyleHead as 1            ,\
    BentArrow_2 i 0 u 1:(CP($2)) @CtrlPoints                ,\
    BentArrow_2 i 1 u 1:2        @StyleArrow lc "web-green" ,\
    BentArrow_2 i 2 u 1:2:3:4    @StyleHead as 2            ,\
    BentArrow_3 i 0 u 1:(CP($2)) @CtrlPoints                ,\
    BentArrow_3 i 1 u 1:2        @StyleArrow lc "blue"      ,\
    BentArrow_3 i 2 u 1:2:3:4    @StyleHead as 3
```

The `BentArrow.fct` file contain:

```
# Implements a bent arrow using Cubic Bézier curves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve)
#
# Usage: call 'BentArrow.fct' tag xi yi yc1 yc1 xc2 yc2 xf yf
# where
#       xi,yi   = start point
#       xc1,yc1 = control point #1
#       xc2,yc2 = control point #2
#       xf,yf   = final point
#
# The algorithm creates 
#     1) a variable named BentArrow_id with 'id' as a integer number,
#        defined by user like a standart arrow, and 
#     2) a datafile (e.g BentArrow_id.bentarrow) containing 
#          i) the control points, 
#         ii) the datapoints to create the curve, and
#        iii) the datapoints do ceate head
# as indexable datablocks (0, 1 and 2, respectively).
# The number of datapoint (samples) used on bent arrow construction
# are defined by 'ArrowPoints' (default 50)

# Receiving the arguments from 'call' command
tag = int(ARG1)
x_i = real(ARG2)
y_i = real(ARG3)
x_1 = real(ARG4)
y_1 = real(ARG5)
x_2 = real(ARG6)
y_2 = real(ARG7)
x_f = real(ARG8)
y_f = real(ARG9)

# Defining the variable to filename, based on 'tag', and creating the datafile
eval sprintf( "%s_%g = %s", 'BentArrow', tag, sprintf("'BentArrow_%g.bentarrow'", tag) )

# Checking if 'ArrowPoints' is defined
if ( !exists("ArrowPoints") ) {
    ArrowPoints = 50
}

# Quadratic Bézier function
DrawArrow(t,p0,p1,p2,p3) = (1-t)**3*p0 + 3*(1-t)**2*t*p1 + 3*(1-t)*t**2*p2 + t**3*p3 # 0 <= t <= 1

# Creating the datafile containing the datapoints to bent arrow
set print sprintf('BentArrow_%g.bentarrow', tag)
    # ----- ControlPoints -----------------------
    print "# Block index 0 (control points)"
    print sprintf("% e\t% e", x_i, y_i)
    print sprintf("% e\t% e", x_1, y_1)
    print ""
    print sprintf("% e\t% e", x_2, y_2)
    print sprintf("% e\t% e", x_f, y_f)
    print ""
    print ""
    # ----- ArrowData -----------------------
    print "# Block index 1 (arrow)"
    do for [i=0:int(ArrowPoints):1] {
        t = i/real(ArrowPoints)
        print sprintf("% e\t% e", DrawArrow(t,x_i,x_1,x_2,x_f), DrawArrow(t,y_i,y_1,y_2,y_f))
    }
    print ""
    print ""
    # ----- ArrowHead -----------------------
    print "# Block index 2 (head)"
    do for [i=int(ArrowPoints)-1:int(ArrowPoints):1] {
        t = i/real(ArrowPoints)
        x_head = x_f - DrawArrow(t,x_i,x_1,x_2,x_f)
        y_head = y_f - DrawArrow(t,y_i,y_1,y_2,y_f)
        print sprintf("% e\t% e\t% e\t% e", DrawArrow(t,x_i,x_1,x_2,x_f), DrawArrow(t,y_i,y_1,y_2,y_f), x_head, y_head)
    }
unset print
```

Improvements will be well received!

Comment: I like your Cubic Bézier approach. I guess that's the preferred and most flexible way to plot bent arrows.
My suggestion about the control points: instead of entering absolute values for the control points, I would prefer the option of relative/absolute angles and relative distances. See my updated answer.