# Gnuplot: gradient coloured arrow

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to draw an arrow with not a single colour, but a colour gradient along its length. Does anyone know how to achieve that? Some pseudo-code for creating an arrow that starts red and ends blue:

```
set palette defined (0 "red", 1 "blue")
set cbr [0:1]
set arrow from 0,0 to 1,1 linecolor palette cb [0:1] # this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides @Friedrich's solution, I would like to suggest a more general solution (although more complicated).

I assume you want to plot something else besides the arrow.
In case your graph needs to use a palette I guess you're in "trouble", because I'm not sure whether gnuplot supports more than one palette in a plot command
(see [Gnuplot 5.2 splot: Multiple pm3d palette in one plot call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57465513/7295599)). So, you have to implement the palette for your arrow by yourself (see e.g. [Gnuplot: transparency of data points when using palette](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60250928/7295599)). If you want to do bent arrows using Cubic Bézier check (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389081/7295599).

**Code:**

```
### arrow with color gradient (besides other palette in plot)
reset session

array A[4] = [-4,-2,4,2]   # arrow coordinates x0,y0,x1,y1
Ax(t) = A[1] + t*(A[3]-A[1])
Ay(t) = A[2] + t*(A[4]-A[2])
AColorStart = 0xff0000   # red
AColorEnd =   0x0000ff   # blue
r(c) = (c & 0xff0000)>>16
g(c) = (c & 0x00ff00)>>8
b(c) = (c & 0x0000ff)
AColor(t) = ((int(r(AColorStart)*(1-t)+r(AColorEnd)*t))<<16) + \
            ((int(g(AColorStart)*(1-t)+g(AColorEnd)*t))<<8)  + \
              int(b(AColorStart)*(1-t)+b(AColorEnd)*t)

array AHead[1]   # dummy array for plotting a single point, here: arrow head
set angle degrees
set style arrow 1 lw 3 lc rgb var size 0.5,15 fixed

set palette grey

plot '++' u 1:2:($1*$2) w image notitle, \
     [0:0.99] '+' u (Ax($1)):(Ay($1)):(AColor($1)) w l lw 3 lc rgb var notitle,\
     AHead u (Ax(0.99)):(Ay(0.99)):(Ax(1)-Ax(0.99)):(Ay(1)-Ay(0.99)):(AColor($1)) w vec as 1 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

For what it is worth, here is a variation which allows plotting of multiple arrows each with a different palette. I guess it requires gnuplot 5.2, because of indexing the datablock `$PALETTE[i]`.

**Code:**

```
### multiple arrows each with different color gradients (besides other palette in plot)
reset session

# define palettes
set print $myPalettes
    test palette                # get default palette into datablock $PALETTE
    print $PALETTE              # add palette to $myPalettes
    set palette rgb 33,13,10    # define next palette
    test palette                # get palette into datablock $PALETTE
    print $PALETTE              # add palette to $myPalettes
    set palette defined (0 "blue", 1 "black", 2 "red")   # define next palette
    test palette                                         # get palette into datablock $PALETTE
    print $PALETTE                                       # add palette to $myPalettes
set print
    
ColorComp(p,t,c) = int(word($myPalettes[p*257+int(255*t)+1],c+1)*0xff)
AColor(p,t) = (ColorComp(p,t,1)<<16) + (ColorComp(p,t,2)<<8) + ColorComp(p,t,3)
           
set size ratio -1
set angle degrees
unset key
set style arrow 1 lw 3 lc rgb var size 0.5,15 fixed
array AHead[1]      # dummy array for plotting a single point, here: arrow head
set palette grey    # yet another palette for the background

# x0 y0 x1  y1  paletteNo
$Arrows <<EOD
-4  -4   4   0   0
-4  -2   4   2   1
-4   0   4   4   2
EOD

Ax(i,t) = word($Arrows[i],1) + t*(word($Arrows[i],3)-word($Arrows[i],1))
Ay(i,t) = word($Arrows[i],2) + t*(word($Arrows[i],4)-word($Arrows[i],2))
Palette(i) = int(word($Arrows[i],5))

plot '++' u 1:2:($1*$2) w image, \
     for [i=1:|$Arrows|] [0:0.99:0.01] '+' u (Ax(i,$1)):(Ay(i,$1)):(AColor(Palette(i),$1)) w l lw 4 lc rgb var, \
     for [i=1:|$Arrows|] AHead u (Ax(i,0.99)):(Ay(i,0.99)): \
         (Ax(i,1)-Ax(i,0.99)):(Ay(i,1)-Ay(i,0.99)):(AColor(Palette(i),$1)) w vec as 1
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Woah, lots of interesting constructions I haven't thought of so far. In my case, there was just one palette, but its still nice to have your solution by hand. I have a question about the vector plot: How many arrows are plotted? I guess this depends on the sampling density? For very high values it could be more efficient to add a single short arrow like @Friedrich proposed.

Comment: glad to hear that this is helpful. Default sampling rate is 100. So, yes, it would be better to plot just one vector. Minimal sampling rate is 2. Probably, you can set sampling individually, but I was not sure how to do this. Anyway, I modified the answer and added another "hack" for the arrowhead using a single arrow.

Answer (score 2):

With `line palette` one can color-code a line. With a second command one could set the head, via `set arrow` or with a plot `vector` command

```
set palette defined (0 "red", 1 "blue")
set cbr [0:1]

set arrow 1 from 0.9,0.9 to 1,1 lc "blue"
plot sample [t=0:1] "+" us (t):(t):(t) w l palette
```

[image]

Thus two commands are necessary. The head of the arrow has single colour, which you have to specify.